# Author Error "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."

Tags: users, capabilities

I have a big problem, I try to login in WordPress as Author and I get a blank screen with this message **"Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page".**

I am new to wordpress and i don't know how to fix this error.

Someone can help me, please!!

Comment: Hi Miten, could you please elaborate the issue? Generally if you are logging into WP as a WP user, then you should never see such message, unless some POST PAGES are not authorized to be accessed for certain user. Do you really get this message as soon as you login? What happens, after you see this message and then remove everything else from url and just point to the root of the site?

Comment: Yes, this message comes up as soon as i login as author, if i change that user role to something else it work fine.

Comment: Did you try pointing to the root of the website after you get the error message? Do you mean that you cannot access the site at all after login as a Author? Are you by chance accessing the login screen following any EDIT link, for which you don't have permission?

Comment: @RakeshMehta i can not access anything in admin panel, but i can see website and it working fine.

Comment: @RakeshMehta Yes, I tried but can not access, but if i directly write url to brower "wp-admin/edit.php" it is accessibl. but can not add new article

Comment: That must be some role related issue. By default WP authorizes Authors to create posts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108411/discussion-between-miten-patel-and-rakesh-mehta).